# Cannot access object on IOS Safari, but works on Desktop Chrome

Tags: javascript, php, laravel

I've created a JavaScript Filter object and including it in laravel blade.php file.
When trying to access the object on windows 10 Chrome it works, but on IOS Safari or Chrome i still get undefined.

```
var filter = new Filter();

var handlesSlider = document.getElementById('filter-price');

var min = parseInt(handlesSlider.dataset.min);
var max = parseInt(handlesSlider.dataset.max) + 1;

noUiSlider.create(handlesSlider, {
    start: [min, max],
    tooltips: true,
    connect: true,
    margin: 5,
    range: {
        'min': min,
        'max': max
    },
    format: {
        // 'to' the formatted value. Receives a number.
        to: function (value) {
            return `${Math.round(value)}€`
        },
        // 'from' the formatted value.
        // Receives a string, should return a number.
        from: function (value) {
            return Number(value.replace(',-', ''));
        }
    }
});


var json = {!! $json !!};
handlesSlider.noUiSlider.on('change.one', function (e) {  

    const min = e[0].replace("€", "");
    const max = e[1].replace("€", "");   

    var filteredProducts = json
    .filter(product =>         
        parseInt(product.price) >= min && 
        parseInt(product.price) <= max);

    filter.render(document.querySelector("{{ $selector }}"), filteredProducts);        
});
filter.render(document.querySelector("{{ $selector }}"), json);       
alert(filter);
```

And Including it in another file as:

```
 @include('components.filter', ['min' => $min, 'max' => $max, 'json' => 
 $products->toJson(), 'selector' => '.product-list__products'])
```

On desktop i get clear alert object object, but on mobile undefined or no alert at all.

Comment: I think everything in your code should be supported by safari, but it could be that something in the libraries is not working in safari... I use sentry.io to debug these things - you will get the error log (if it actually crashes) in the sentry web console so you can find out what is it that's not working in safari.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was that, ios 13.1.3 cannot understand JS Arrow functions and also modules.